# Absolute path url not working on img source HTML element

Tags: html, node.js, image, pdf, bundle

I'm building a node module that builds reports using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme).
I got an html file in which I'm trying to access images in ways like:

These images are under `src/templates/` and bundled as `dist/templates`.
This should be consumed from a nextjs application.

What I noticed is that the absolute path worked for me, I mean, if I print it points to the image.
For full path: i'm doing `path.join(__dirname, "templates", "header-footer.png")`

tsconfig.json

```
 {
      "include": ["src", "types"],
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true
      }
    }
```

Any clues about this?

I've tried also to use a URL relative to the root directory of the site su

```
<img src="/templates/header-footer.png" />
```

Comment: what you et when you print this ? path.join(__dirname, "templates", "header-footer.png")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get
C:\Users\me\etc\etc\reports-lib\dist\templates\header-footer.png
Is pointing to my pc directory, not consumer

Comment: normal too have etc two time ? and i code is hosted on your computer i think that's the raison why it's point on it , when i look for online exemple it's relative , https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_met_path_join

Comment: This is part of a private node module that i'm publishing at npm. The consumer of this is a nextjs application.

The question is, how should be the path formed at <img src /> in terms of allowing the module to be consumed of any application

Comment: oh i see , sorry out of my abilities for the moment but good luck

Answer (score 0):

So, after burning my brain for some days, i found that i have to define a basepath within the lib options as this

```
 var options = {
    format: "A4",
    base: "file:///" + __dirname + "/",
    localUrlAccess: true, // set this to true to enable local file access
  };
```

and in my html refer to he files as:

```
src="templates/header-logo.png"
```

This works.